# Move changes from one folder to another

Tags: git

I have been working inside a directory where I have totally change the behaviour of a product that is confined to this directory. I have made commits that change the content of this directory, but I have not yet pushed this upstream.

Then the blue-shirts come along and tells me that the old system is still needed, and that the changes I have made should be a separate project. **Thus I would like to be able to copy the original folder and re-apply all the changes to this new folder.** Or in other words, move changes from one folder to another.

What I would like to do in pseudo-git/bash:

```
VERYOLDCOMMIT="$(git rev-parse HEAD~23)"
LATESTCOMMIT="$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
git checkout $VERYOLDCOMMIT
cp directory1/ directory2
git add directory2
git commit -m "Duplicating directory1 to directory2"
pseudo-git apply-changes-from-directory1-LATESTCOMMIT-to-directory2
pseudo-git remove all changes/commits from directory1
```

Is there a way to achieve this, or would I have to checkout the `VERYOLDCOMMIT` and start re-applying the changes manually inside the new directory, creating new commits as I go?

I have looked at `git am` but have not quite seen a way to achieve what I want.

I could also potentially do an `interactive rebase` and just move all changes over to the new folder, but it would probably be a lot of work.

The end result should be in the same git repository and on the same branch.

*Ps.: It is important that I keep the changes. Otherwise I would just have made a brute giant commit with the new directory*

Comment: At the beginning you say "working inside a directory" -- just for clarification, I assume this is a hit repository and "working" means you've been doing commits?  And are these commits being shared with an upstream repository?  Finally, does this new project have to go into a separate git repository?  Or could it be another branch in the existing repository?

Comment: I will update the question; but I have commits inside a subdirectory. These changes are not in upstream yet (thankfully). The en result should be inside the same git repository, on the same branch, but in a different subfolder.